# How to set the transaction isolation level of a Postgres Datasource

Tags: java, postgresql, transactions, java-ee-5

How do I set the global transaction isolation level for a postgres data source.

I'm running on jboss and I'm using hibernate to connect.

I know that I can set the isolation level from hibernate, does this work for Postgres?

This would be by setting the hibernate.connection.isolation hibernate property to 1,2,4,8 - the various values of the relevant static fields.

I'm using the org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set isolation level that way.  Hibernate allows you to do it in a database-agnostic way, so it'll work with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Hibernate In Action book mentions: "Hibernate never changes the isolation level of connections obtained from a datasource provided by the application server in a managed environment." You're better off setting isolation level in JBoss' DS config as Alexander T answered.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not using Hibernate or just prefer to set the isolation level in the data source, all JBoss datasources support the `<transaction-isolation>` tag:

```
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>GenericDS</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>[jdbc: url for use with Driver class]</connection-url>
    <driver-class>[fully qualified class name of java.sql.Driver implementation]</driver-class>
    <user-name>x</user-name>
    <password>y</password>
    <!-- you can include connection properties that will get passed in 
     the DriverManager.getConnection(props) call-->
    <!-- look at your Driver docs to see what these might be -->
    <connection-property name="char.encoding">UTF-8</connection-property>
    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE</transaction-isolation>
    [...]
```

I got this information from the [JBoss wiki](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/configdatasources)